# Script to combine data from one file to another

Tags: bash, database

I have a file containing folders name/value pairs:

```
peter:/home/peter/
max:/home/max-lucas/
judith:/home/judith/documents/
```

I have another file containing files name/value pairs, with the same names:

```
max:todo.txt
peter:calendar.txt
peter:notes.txt
peter:dummy.txt
```

This is a kind of database.
The real files are not so simple. I have to extract the data with sed, but this is not the point.

I want to concatenate the two files:

```
/home/peter/calendar.txt
/home/peter/notes.txt
/home/peter/dummy.txt
/home/max-lucas/todo.txt
```

The only idea I have is:

1. iterate into the first file to create a name/value array
2. iterate through the second file and assemble each line with the correct value from the array

Question: is there a somewhat standard CLI tool made for this?

Comment: Is there a restriction to use bash for this scenario, because things will  become much more complex when you have to manage arrays and dictionary in bash, which will be much more simpler and manageable when you use some traditional programming language like python.

Comment: This is not a restriction, because the question is about the existence of a tool doing the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk it is easy:

```
awk -F ":" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a { print a[$1]$2}' homedir.txt file.txt
```

Comment: That was pretty much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a cli tool for this, but I might have find a way to iterate through your files to retrieve the output you wanted.
First we need to create a key value pair of users and their directories.

```
declare -A users
for i in $(cat file1);do users+=( [$(echo $i | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')]=$(echo $i | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')) ; done
```

Now we have created a key value pair.
You can verify this by displaying the contents of the dictionary

```
for i in "${!users[@]}"; do echo "$i - ${users["$i"]}"; done
```

Now we will iterate through second file and in the print statement we will replace the user with its directory.

```
for i in $(cat file2);do echo ${users[$(echo $i|awk -F ':' '{print $1}')]}$(echo $i|awk -F ':' '{print $2}')  ; done
```

this showed me the sample output that you have showed us.